# How do I connect components to the Arduino with a motorshield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

How would I connect components to the Arduino with this motor shield?

[image: Arduino motor shield]

Thanks :)

Comment: What components? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @NickGammon for example if i wanted to hook up a rc reciever? or just something to the arduino e.g. i want to use the pins of the arduino? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are up for a little soldering, look into [stackable Arduino headers](https://www.adafruit.com/product/85). (Feel free to shop around for those, adafruit was just the first result.) You could then use [male jumpers](https://www.google.com/search?q=male%20jumpers%20electronic&tbm=isch) and a breadboard to connect anything that fits in a breadboard.

Just be careful to avoid pins that the shield is already using.

Comment: How would I attach them to the shield?

Comment: First, [desolder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N7rCttQJJE) the old headers on the shield, then follow the Make It section of [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-proto-shield-arduino/make-it) to attach the new headers.